# Push array of checkbox values to hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am running this code and it returns me set of values which are checked

```
var a = [];
var cboxes = $('input[name="suppcheck[]"]:checked');
    var len = cboxes.length;
    for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
        a[i] = cboxes[i].value;
       //document.getElementByName('suppgrp[]').value = a[i];

    }
```

I have a hidden field with ID suppgrp where I want to push all these values  retrieved and wanted to pass it in array..

But I am not able to...where am I going wrong?

Comment: pass it outside the for loop

Answer (score 1):

i have added some extra code which when page load then will call this function and also when change checkbox value then also call this function so all time it will work

```js
loadCheck(); // initial call this function to load data

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function()
    {
        loadCheck();

    });

    function loadCheck() {
        $('#hiddenValue').val('');
        $('#showValue').val('');
        var checkboxes = $('input[name="suppcheck[]"]:checked');
        var data = [];
        var len = checkboxes.length;
        for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
            data[i] = checkboxes[i].value;

        }
        $('#hiddenValue').val(data);
         $('#showValue').val(data);
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="4" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="5" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="6" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="7" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="8" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="suppcheck[]" value="9" />

    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue" />
    <input type="text" id="showValue" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [];

jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function()   
{

 var cboxes = jQuery('input[name="suppcheck[]"]:checked');
 var len = cboxes.length;
 var alval = '';
 for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    a[i] = cboxes[i].value;
    if (alval != '') {
      alval += ','+a[i];
    }else{
      alval = a[i];
    }
 }

 jQuery('#myhidden').val(alval);

});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to it